# Method for array of given size containing random integers between given min and max

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I have to do this in Java:

> Write a method fillArray() that takes three integers: (s, min, max),
> and returns an array of size s having random integers with values
> between min and max.

This is the code I wrote

```java
public static void fillArray(int s, int min, int max) {
    int[] random = new int[s];

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        int n = (int) (Math.random()*100 %s);
        if (n > min && n < max) {
            random[i] = n;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("Here's an array of size %d, whose elements vary between %d and %d: \n", s, min, max);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(random));
}
```

The problem is, when I implement my method in the main, `fillArray(10, 10, 20)`, it gives me arrays of size 10, with elements at 0.

I tried playing around with this specific expression in the code

```java
int n = (int) (Math.random()*100 %s);
```

and changing what I do after *100.

Sometimes it works for most elements, but I still get some elements which are 0, which is wrong since the minimum is 10.

Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: The n value is never greater than the min value because the modulus operator gives you remainder when you divide the number by 10,  you get a value less than 10.

Comment: Hint: your loop iterates ONCE over your array. But you have a condition in there that REJECTS some elements. So: you need a different kind of loop. You can only progress to the next element of your array once you found a VALID answer. Also not that the `100%s` is not necessary. The Random class has methods that allow you to directly retrieve random ints in a specific interval.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java for example.

Comment: unfortunately I must use this format... this is an intro course to JAVA and I cannot use stuff I did not learn in class or else I will not be awarded the whole grade @GhostCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.random()
```

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

So since the random numbers you generate are always between `[0 - 1) (Zero inclusive & 1 exclusiv` you need to multiply them by your desired max number to generate random numbers which are greter than one. Example to generate random numbers between `[0 - 15)` you can do

```
Math.random() * 15
```

to get values between `[0.0 - 14.999..]`.

To include 15 in your values you need to multiply with `(15 + 1) = 16`

```
Math.random() * (15 + 1) or generaly
Math.random() * (max + 1)
```

Since there is also a min value in your requierment, you need to exclude values between `0 - min`. To do so you could add simply the min value to the result of the above:

```
(Math.random() * (max + 1)) + min
```

But wait, let see an example for `min = 5` and `max = 15`. Since

```
Math.random() * (max + 1)
```

returns values between `[0.0 - 15.999..]` adding `min = 5` to each value:

```
(Math.random() * (max + 1)) + min
```

will result in values in range `[5.0 - 20.999..]` which is not desired. To change that you will need to substract min from max while multiplying:

```
(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

which will result in the correct range `[5.0 - 15.999..]` where you need to apply casting `(int)` to get your random integers instead of dobles. So your method could look like

```
public static void fillArray(int s, int min, int max) {
    int[] random = new int[s];

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        int n = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        random[i] = n;
    }

    System.out.printf("Here's an array of size %d, whose elements vary between %d and %d: \n", s, min, max);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(random));
}
```